# DateInterval properties and isset()

Tags: php, datetime

While running some tests and noticed that checking public properties on DateInterval objects return false even tho they contain data. Why is this/what are we missing from the documentation?

Example:

```
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$targetDate = new DateTime('2015-03-05 11:11:11');
$interval = $currentDate->diff($targetDate);
var_dump($interval->y);
var_dump($interval->m);
var_dump(isset($interval->y));
var_dump(isset($interval->m));
var_dump($interval);
```

Will give the following output:

```
int(0)
int(2)
bool(false)
bool(false)
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(2)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["h"]=>
  int(9)
  ["i"]=>
  int(43)
  ["s"]=>
  int(35)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(1)
  ["days"]=>
  int(62)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($interval)` before you do the others. I cannot see how the `->m` could just "vanish" like that. if it wasn't set, then there'd be no way it could ever have `2` in it for the previous dump, especially since you're not modifying the interval object in any way.

Comment: I added the requested var_dump output to the initial question for formatting's sake (php 5.6)

Comment: Managed to find this bug after a lot of confusion today.. crazy stuff

Comment: Can you please tell me what are these properties? 
weekday
weekday_behavior
first_last_day_of
invert
special_type
special_amount
have_weekday_relative
have_special_relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely interesting. Check this out:

```
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$targetDate = new DateTime('2015-03-05 11:11:11');
$interval = $currentDate->diff($targetDate);
echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($interval); --> if you uncomment this line, it will work just fine
var_dump($interval->y);
var_dump($interval->m);
var_dump(isset($interval->y));
var_dump(isset($interval->m));
```

Doing a `var_dump($interval)` before calling `isset()` prints the correct results!

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(2)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["h"]=>
  int(9)
  ["i"]=>
  int(49)
  ["s"]=>
  int(33)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(1)
  ["days"]=>
  int(62)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
int(0)
int(2)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

I think you must have really stumbled upon one of those quirks in the language. There is nothing I can think of related to `var_dump` or `isset` or PHP's OOP implementation for that matter, which can cause this behavior. Perhaps a bug report to PHP?

Comment: if you print the object it does seem to force the values. Seems pretty quirky to me.

Comment: yup - its almost like printing the object somehow "materializes" the properties it has. At least as far as isset is concerned, because we already know that the properties have values since printing them directly worked just fine.

Comment: I'm going to file a bug report, I was pretty certain  there was something we were doing incorrectly.

Comment: Bug report filed. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69587 I will update this post if/when I get a reply. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Awesome! I will monitor that bug ticket too.

Comment: Seems fixed in PHP 7.0.14